# How to set connection string towards website hosted on IIS by specifying hostname header

Tags: c#, iis, networking, dns

I have my .net core api that wants to access a service which is hosted on another server. My current working connection string is:

```
"AuthorityUrl": "https://identity.test.company.eu/"
```

The https://identity.test.company.eu is a website listening on a Server whose address is 192.168.41.2 . This website is hosted on IIS and listening to all *unassigned ip* with hostname in the bindings set to *identity.test.company.eu* . This means that IIS redirects the call towards this specific website. How does it do it? It reads that the incoming http call has hostname header equals to *identity.test.company.eu* and therefore is able to route the call.
Now, let's say that I don't have access to the DNS mapping and that I have to set manually in my connection string that I want to send a request to the 192.168.41.2 server and include in the call the hostname header *identity.test.company.eu* . In such a way IIS on the server redirects the call towards the right website. How can I do this?

Thansk!

Comment: @LexLi sorry I don't really get the answer.. I need to find a way to specify the right connection string from within my .net core app. That's supposed to be the url that Identity Server hooks up from the appsettings.json for doing its autenthication stuff. Curl is not the right way..

Comment: @LexLi but that's already the working solution I posted in the question.. I am asking a way to set directly the ip address in the connection string with also the hostname